# How do I buy a PSN gift card for a friend in another continent?

Tags: ps4, psn

I don't have a PS4 console or PSN account but since you can't gift games directly I want to gift my friend a gift card. They live in Asia and I live in North America. Would I have to make an Asian PSN account or a NA one? I want to make sure the gift works for them so can someone please explain to me the logistics of it?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I buy a PSN gift card for a friend in another continent?

You just buy codes from online retailers from a different country. For example, at least in Singapore, it's Lazada, SEAGM, eClubStore to name a few. These retailers typically charge about 5-10% above retail value (at exchange rates), but they stock codes from many other regions.

> What are the logistics?

You pay, they take a code from a list of codes that they have (and obviously have not used, because their aim is to sell them legitimately, not scam you). After that, they or their servers give you a code that they have and you use it.

They usually buy codes off many sources, which includes directly from Valve.

> What about scam?

There's nothing stopping them from giving you a fraudalent code, so you have to do your research and see who is credible. You can try a proper store, or find an individual seller.

General rule is: If it's below market price (and after exchange rates), it's likely to be a scam. The stores I've listed above have worked for me, and have assisted in times when my codes do not work.

Comment: Thanks can you link some of the stores you buy from? And the code how do I know that it will work in their regional account?

Comment: Really, if its not to be a surprise, I would say ask your friend or someone who lives there where they would buy the card from. You'll get what is a true shop overthere and what is just a site trying to scam you (i'd guess a true, brick and mortar store will not scam your ass.)